# Simple.Data, how to select when column name contains ?, -, / and other special character?

Tags: simple.data

I am using Simple.Data to query the DB. but this particular DB is imported from Access DB.

some of the filed names has space, -, / in it.

```
Policy Number
FTZ?
Prod/Co
Covg - Years
```

is it possible to use Simple.Data? how do you name your object so Simple.Data will know which field to query.

```
public class item {
  public string "Policy Number" {get; set;}
  public string "FTZ?" {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just leave out non-alphanumeric characters in your identifiers, and Simple.Data will still find the matching columns.

e.g.

`Item item = db.Items.FindByPolicyNumber(pnum);`

Comment: thank you so much. saved me hrs to figure it out myself.

Comment: For more info on this and how to customize how Simple.Data behaves check out the Advanced Naming Scenarios section at the bottom of http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Start/NamingConventions.html